# Proper set of operators to log execution time with disposals on timeouts

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java2

I need to log the time every time the upstream is subscribed to. That's fine, cause you can do

```
fun <T> Single<T>.markTime(name: () -> String): Single<T> = this
    .doOnEvent { _, _ -> markElapsedTime(name() + "-on-event") }
```

However, this won't work for disposals. So we add

```
fun <T> Single<T>.markTime(name: () -> String): Single<T> = this
    .doOnEvent { _, _ -> markElapsedTime(name() + "-on-event") }
    .doOnDispose { markElapsedTime(name() + "-dispose") }
```

But this logs some events twice. How to avoid this? There seems to be no built-in rx operator which supports this. Not that `doFinally` won't work since it does the job only after downstream. We need to perform the action before calling downstream and be able to log disposals.

Of course you may do

```
fun <T> Single<T>.markTime(name: () -> String): Single<T> = compose {
    var alreadyLogged = false
    it.doOnEvent { _, _ ->
        markElapsedTime(name())
        alreadyLogged = true
    }.doOnDispose { if (!alreadyLogged) markElapsedTime(name()) }
}
```

But this is a hack.